# How could embed multiple WARs (or Java Web Applications, using Spring MVC specifically) in a single web page that hosts the other?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, web, frameworks

I have one Spring MVC Application and I want to split it in to multiple applications (each one deployed separetely) but having one main application that manage the security and the header, lateral menu and footer of the [classic layout](http://tiles.apache.org/framework/images/tiled_page.png).

What I really want is that whenever the user clicks a button on the side menu, the main application calls the appropriate application to fill the body. The main application has to be able to call the application server that contains the appropriate WAR, but instead to give it the control to draw the entire page only allow him drawing the body.

Sorry for my horrible english.

Comment: Maybe could have servlets in the main application that catch requests to other application servers and manipulate them by adding or removing headers and things like that, but that would be a solution of very low level... 
I would hope that you could do this much  better.
By the way, would also need to share session information between applications to keep security

Comment: Just to clarify, you want ApplicationA and ApplicationB to share the same look/layout?

Comment: No, I don't want that. I want an ApplicationA to draw the header, menu, and footer but ApplicationB, ApplicationC, ApplicationD, ApplicationE as candidates to draw the body. I know who really going to paint the body will be ApplicationA but using the server's responses from ApplicationB, ApplicationC, ApplicationD or ApplicationE.

Comment: The reason is that the code is too large and needs to be modularized because it contains code of business units that are completely different and should not be impacted at every deploy to production, but in addition they must all have the same entry point. For the user should be seen as a single application.
Thanks Neil

Comment: Sounds like you need two or more apps.  One main app that simply hosts the layout with headers and menus with the other apps used for the body? I think you are either looking at frames or iframes, or you are going to have to make your sub-apps return HTML fragments and the main app simply appends those fragments into the completed page.

Comment: Yes CodeChimp! iFrames could be useful... but how could integrate it supossing that ApplicationA, ApplicationB, ApplicationC, etc. are all of them Spring MVC Applications? and how could share session and navigation information between the main app and the others?

Comment: In fact, is not absolutely necessary that the ApplicationA only manage the layout, rather,  that ApplicationA  could open a frame inside of himself on which could loading other Spring MVC Applications sharing the session and navigation information.